# Identity in inner product space

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $x$ and $y$ be elements of inner product space, such that $\| x+2y \|^2=5$ and $\| 2x+y \|^2=4$

Prove that $9 \| x+y\|^2 + \| x-y\|^2 =18$

Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$||x+2y||^2 = (x+2y,x+2y) = (x,x) + 4(x,y) + 4(y,y) = 5$, and

$||2x+y||^2 = (2x+y,2x+y) = 4(x,x) + 4(x,y) + (y,y) = 4$. Add these equations and multiply both by $2$ we have:

$10(x,x) + 16(x,y) + 10(y,y) = 18 = 9||x+y||^2 +||x-y||^2$

Comment: Can you explain the last line? I don't get it...

Answer (score 4):

**Hint** $$\|a+b\|^2 + \|a-b\|^2 = 2 \|a\|^2 + 2 \|b\|^2.$$

Choose suitable $a$ and $b$.

Comment: @8pir It is a **hint**. In fact, I want luka5z to think about it; I guess, it is homework.

Comment: @8pir I did upvote, because it **does** lead to a solution. While I certainly wouldn't go as far as to say that I "know math", I think I'm competent enough to say it's a fine answer.

Comment: @8pir If you read some of my other answers, you will see that I don't care whether I get upvotes or not and that I, often enough, give full solutions instead of hints. But in this case, again, I guess it is homework and it doesn't help the OP when I solve the problem for him.